# `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined` only inside the loop

Tags: reactjs

I have registered my `processForm` function in the constructor using:

> this.processForm = this.processForm.bind(this);

Now the strange thing is that my function recognizes `this.state.Fields` but inside the loop it fails to recognize `this` seeing it as `undefined`.

```
processForm() {
    //validate entire form
    var validForm=true;
    this.state.Fields.forEach(function(field){
        if(field.props.required === "1"){
        var validField=(field.props.value != '' && field.props.value != undefined);

                if( ! validField) {
            if(field.props.name == 'controlLabel') {
                this.setState({errControlLabelStyle: '1px solid red'});
        } else {
                this.setState({errControlLabelStyle: ''});
        }

        if(field.props.name == 'fieldType') {
            this.setState({errFieldTypeStyle: '1px solid red'});
        } else {
            this.setState({errFieldTypeStyle: ''});
        }                   
        }
    });
    //after validation, data post to server
    if (validForm) {
    ...

    }

}
```

Comment: I had problem like this with map. For solve this i used 
someList.map(function(item) {
  ...
}, this)

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
forEach takes second argument for set this inside fucntion.

Answer (score 1):

try to do something like this. this happened because you trying to call "this" from callback context.

```
processForm() {
        //validate entire form
        var that = this;
        var validForm=true;
        this.state.Fields.forEach(function(field){
            if(field.props.required === "1"){
            var validField=(field.props.value != '' && field.props.value != undefined);

                    if( ! validField) {
                if(field.props.name == 'controlLabel') {
                    that.setState({errControlLabelStyle: '1px solid red'});
            } else {
                    that.setState({errControlLabelStyle: ''});
            }

            if(field.props.name == 'fieldType') {
                that.setState({errFieldTypeStyle: '1px solid red'});
            } else {
                that.setState({errFieldTypeStyle: ''});
            }                   
            }
        });
        //after validation, data post to server
        if (validForm) {
        ...

        }

    }
```

Comment: not much has changed - no error now, but the state still does not get set

Comment: try to add event bind at your template using this syntax ::this.processForm. if it does't help can you show your full class?

Answer (score 1):

you can either make a ref to `this` to use inside the loop, or use the fat arrow ES6 syntax to preserve the context of `this` inside your loop:

try this :

```
processForm() {
    //validate entire form
    var validForm=true;
    var self = this;
    this.state.Fields.forEach(function (field) {
        if(field.props.required === "1"){
        var validField=(field.props.value != '' && field.props.value != undefined);

                if( ! validField) {
            if(field.props.name == 'controlLabel') {
                self.setState({errControlLabelStyle: '1px solid red'});
        } else {
                self.setState({errControlLabelStyle: ''});
        }

        if(field.props.name == 'fieldType') {
            self.setState({errFieldTypeStyle: '1px solid red'});
        } else {
            self.setState({errFieldTypeStyle: ''});
        }                   
        }
    });
    //after validation, data post to server
    if (validForm) {
    ...

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a `binding` issue to avoid this kind of problems, always use `arrow functions` instead of `callback functions`, use this code:

```
processForm() {
    //validate entire form
    var validForm = true;
    this.state.Fields.forEach((field) => {
        if(field.props.required === "1"){
        var validField = (field.props.value != '' && field.props.value != undefined);

        if(!validField){
            if(field.props.name == 'controlLabel'){
                this.setState({errControlLabelStyle: '1px solid red'});
            }else {
                this.setState({errControlLabelStyle: ''});
            }

            if(field.props.name == 'fieldType') {
                this.setState({errFieldTypeStyle: '1px solid red'});
            }else{
                this.setState({errFieldTypeStyle: ''});
            }                   
        }
    });

    //after validation, data post to server
    if (validForm) {
    ...

    }

}
```

Note: there is a mismatch of opening and closing braces in your ques, so make sure all the braces are closed at proper place, just replace the line in which you are using `forEach` loop.

Comment: it seems to work but the style of the controls does not change. `errControlLabelStyle` stays blank

Comment: @ElenaDBA r u sure about `field.props.name` i think it should be `field.name` ??? can you put the `console.log` on `this.state.fields` and paste the output in ur ques ? it is required to cross check the `if` condition.

Comment: @Mayank Shukla, yes, I am positive. It is a custom control, so I can only access its properties via `field.props`

Comment: then in that use you need to put console on `field.props.name` and check why if condition is not returning true, `console.log(field.props.name, field.props.name == 'controlLabel')` also check the value of `validField`

Comment: i think you used extra `!` in this line `if(!validField)` it should be `if(validField)`....

Comment: It should only run if control is not valid, hence the `! validField`

Comment: the control is something like this: `<Control ref="controlLabel" name="controlLabel" type="1" onComponentMounted={this.register} label="Control Label:" required="1" value={this.state.controlLabel} localChange={this.handleControlLabelChange} inputStyle={{border: this.state.errControlLabelStyle}} />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136275/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-elenadba).